# Email no longer being returned through Facebook oauth

Tags: facebook, facebook-oauth

I had a Facebook signup/login set up on my web site using Oauth. One of the pieces of data that it pulled back was email, which I included in the scope of my call to the API

```
http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=[appID]&redirect_uri=[encoded_URL]&scope=email,user_likes,publish_stream
```

This gets redirected to a page with the following code:

```
$code = $_GET['code'];

$tokenURL = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=[appID]&redirect_uri=[encoded_url]&client_secret=[secret_key]&code=" . $code;


// request access token
//use curl and not file_get_contents()
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $tokenURL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
$accessToken = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$graphURL = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?" . $accessToken;

// request user data using the access token
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $graphURL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
$tempUser = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

//decode the json array to get user data
$user = json_decode($tempUser);

//store user data
$firstName = cleanWords($user->first_name);
$lastName = cleanWords($user->last_name);
$email = cleanEmail($user->email);
```

This used to work fine, but then I suddenly discovered that the email is no longer being returned in the JSON object, even if the user gives permission to supply the email when they first use the app. Was there a change to the API so that email needs to be treated differently now? I saw one post that said that if the user hasn't given explicit permission in their user settings to share their email with apps, then it won't get returned, but I couldn't find any such setting in my account.

Could someone please either point me to where that setting is so I can test whether that's the issue, or let me know if the email is no longer accessible in the same way, and what I would need to change?
Thanks,

Update: I got this working by rewriting my code completely to use the new Facebook API.

Answer (score 0):

I've verified that this isn't a code problem: there's just something different about the particular Facebook account that I was testing with. Not sure what yet, but since this is a Facebook usage question and not a code question, this can be considered answered.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, did you find out what was causing it?